# Unsuccessful download on Firefox/IE - works with an echo after the file print

Tags: php

I'm trying to make available for download a file stored as a blob on my database. For this i have a php script that is basically:

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
//application/pdf
header("Content-Type: ". $file_type);
//integer
header("Content-Length: " . $file_size);
//urlencode to avoid problem with locale special characters
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.urlencode($novo_nome).'"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");

//the file binary content
print($file_stream);
```

Using this script will lead to unsuccessful download on Firefox/IE. In Chrome the download works just fine. One of my coworkers added a dummy echo after the last line:

```
echo "f";
```

After adding this echo, the download started working on Firefox/IE. I thought that the $file_size could be wrong, and tried to send `$file_size-1` to the header function instead of adding the echo, but that didn't work.

Anyone have any clues on why this echo thing works, and what is the right solution?

Comment: Have you tried `$file_size+1` for `Content-Length`?

Comment: It worked! Thank you. But why the former does work on Chrome, and not on Firefox/IE?

Comment: Most likely one waits for the socket to get closed, the others for the right count of bytes.

Comment: I've just verified the difference on file sizes. In the two test files i have, the difference between the `strlen($file_stream)` and `$file_size` was of 1 and 2 bytes. By summing one on the `$file_size`, the differences went to 2 and 3 bytes. I think there's still some unknown reason for this problem.